# How to detect android soft keyboard "Will Show" event

Tags: android, html, cordova, input, keyboard

I have a cordova android app.
I'm trying to prevent native android keyboard to show when user clicks on html input, or input gets focus programmatically. 
It there for android something like:

```
keyboard.addEventListener('will-show', 
   functon(event){
     event.disableKeyboardShow();
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is an event like you pointed. But you can prevent keyboard to showup automatically by doing this:

1) Insert on your onCreate():

```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view == null) {
        view = new View(this);
    }
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

2) Then you assure your EditText can get focus when needed by adding `android:focusable="true"` and  `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` elements in the parent layout of EditText like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout" android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
```

If you don't want your EditText to get focus anyway, put `false` at elements on step 2 and insert another one: `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

Comment: The situation is that i have only webView with html hage inside, and i need to disable keyboard when user clicks on regular html input, textarea (not native android EditText)